# ¿Buscar un TextBox dentro de una tabla en VBA - Word?

Tags: vba, macros

tengo una tabla de una única columna, en algunas filas tengo unos textbox asignados a una macro que funciona perfectamente. Pero necesito consultar el número de la fila en la que se encuentran los TextBox. ¿Sería posible?

Gracias por su atención.

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

he encontrado la solución lo dejo aquí por si alguien lo necesita:

```
If Selection.Find.Execute(Me.TextBoxintroducir el código aquí) = True Then
    ...
End If
```

Un saludo.